# Internet Explorer 9 ActiveXObject returning Object doesn't support this property or method

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer-9

I am trying to create an Ajax request that will work on ie9+. I am using ActiveXObject for ie9, and normal XMLHttpRequest for modern browsers. I get the error 'Object doesn't support this property or method ' or "No such interface supported" if i skip the domParser function. Here is my code:

```
var loadHtmlComponent = function(urlAddress, callback) {


if (window.ActiveXObject) {
    xhr = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP')
    xhr.data
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {

        if (xhr.readystate === 4) {
            // catch xml return and parse into DOM

            var domParser = new DOMParser();

            var oDoc = domParser.parseFromString(xhr.responseXML, 'text/xml');

            var output = oDoc;

            // serialize
            var oXmlSerializer =  new XMLSerializer();
            var sXmlString = oXmlSerializer.serializeToString(output);                
            callback(sXmlString);

        }
    }

    xhr.open('GET', urlAddress);
    xhr.send();

} else {
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onload = function() {
        console.log('XML INSIDE');
        callback(this.responseXML);
    };
    xhr.open('GET', urlAddress);
    xhr.responseType = 'document';
    xhr.send();
};
```

};

can anyone tell me how I can fix this? to work on IE9?

thank you so much

Comment: Why to use ActiveX, [XMLHttpRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535874(v=vs.85).aspx) constructor has been supported in IEs since IE7.

Comment: I believe the reason we used AcitveX is because IE9 couldn't parse the XML return properly.

Comment: Hmm... Switching to ActiveX doesn't fix problems with IE's DOMParser.

Comment: Yeah, i'm sadly learning that the hard way I think. Thanks for the replies.

Comment: So what is the actual error that you are trying to fix.